# How to change the name of a picture selected by client and save it in Server with a different name

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading, input-type-file

I have the following code to upload to my server an image than the user sends through an input type=file.

My questions is: How can I change the name of the file?

Example: let's say than the user upload the following file: "mypicture.jpg" and I want to save it with the name of a variable I have stored, like $username where $username = John so even the user selected "mypicture.jpg" the file will be save in my directory (/var/www/html/images/) as John.jpg

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

$uploaddir = '/var/www/html/images/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
   pg_close();
 }

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3000000" />
Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename = $username . '.' . end($temp);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/var/www/html/images/" . $newfilename);
```